# How to automatically choose which css to use depending on the URL/website and/or server I'm on?

Tags: html, css, knockout.js

I have a HTML widget/table that is pulling info from a private server that diplays the info I want in the selected fields using JSON/knockoutjs data-bindings from a javascript viewmodel file.  I will be putting this widget on different servers/sites.  The problem is that (as silly as it is) I need to use different CSS's depending on which site/server I'm on.  Is there a way in either HTML or Javascript to say that if I go to this website or server use this CSS or if I visit this site/server use the other CSS file I have?

If it's even possible still; maybe there's a way to say if a website url or server contains a specific word; for example: http://abcdEXAMPLEefghi.com; in this example I would check to see if the word "EXAMPLE" was in the URL and if so, use CSS2 instead of the default CSS1.

Comment: You want to do this on client side or server side ??

Comment: in javascript you could check the domain, but this would make your css dependent from javascript: so probably it's better use some kind of server side detection instead (e.g. via `htaccess`).

Comment: @F.Calderan Forgive me as I'm new to this, but since the HTML table (trying to make it an app) is talking to a server and populating it's info from it; and the client could choose which URL to visit; my guess would be to make it on the client side.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe something like this?

http://jsfiddle.net/pqLVz/

```
<script>
    if (window.location.href.indexOf('net') > 0) {
        document.write('<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/css/basicsite.css" />')
        document.write('<style>p { color: red; }</style>')
    }
</script>
<p>hello</p>
```

Comment: YES!! thank you.  I didn't need the second line in the if statement though, just the document.write('<link.....>) line was needed to get the page to load the appropriate style sheet for my table.

Comment: This is a similar approach to the how the HTML5 Boilerplate approaches link to CDN hosted JQuery with fallback-to-local copy.